# Hibernate ORM produce unwanted SQL updates on flush after persisting transient entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I have Parent-child entities mapped by JPA annotations:

Wnen I create new instanse of parent entity, add some fields and call persist method from JPA provider. I got unwanted sql update.
Why hibernate produce it?

```
Hibernate: insert into field_type (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into template (id, client_id, name) values (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select template_f_.id from field_type template_f_ where template_f_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into field (id, field_name_id, operation_template_id, field_value) values (default, ?, ?, ?)
(!)  Hibernate: update field set operation_template_id=? where id=?
```

class Template with subclasses:

```java
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMPLATE")
public class Template {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID", updatable = false)
   private Long clientId;

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name = "OPERATION_TEMPLATE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   private Set<Field> fields = new HashSet<>();

   // getters and setters

   @Entity(name = "Field")
   @Table(name = "FIELD")
   public static class Field {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "ID")
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
      @JoinColumn(name = "FIELD_NAME_ID", nullable = false)
      private FieldType name;

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
      @JoinColumn(name = "OPERATION_TEMPLATE_ID", nullable = false)
      private Template template;

      @Column(name = "FIELD_VALUE", nullable = false)
      private String value;

     // getters and setters
   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "FIELD_TYPE")
   public static class FieldType {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "ID")
      private Long id;

      @Column(name = "TYPE_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
      private String name;

     // getters and setters
   }
}
```

Dao classes

```java
@Repository
public class FieldTypeDao {
   @PersistenceContext
   protected EntityManager entityManager;

   @Transactional
   public void saveAsNew(Template.FieldType fieldType) {
      entityManager.persist(fieldType);
      entityManager.flush();
   }
}

@Repository
public class TemplateDao {

   @PersistenceContext
   protected EntityManager entityManager;

   @Transactional
   public void saveAsNew(Template template) {
      entityManager.persist(template);
      entityManager.flush();
   }
}
```

Config and main class

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoHbnApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoHbnApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

Test:

```java
package com.example;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoHbnApplication.class)
public class TemplateDaoTest {

   @Autowired
   private TemplateDao  templateDao;

   @Autowired
   private FieldTypeDao fieldTypeDao;

   @Test
   public void testSave() throws Exception {
      Template template = new Template();
      template.setName("test template name");
      Template.Field     field     = new Template.Field();
      Template.FieldType fieldType = new Template.FieldType();
      fieldType.setId(1L);
      fieldType.setName("example type");
      fieldTypeDao.saveAsNew(fieldType);
      field.setName(fieldType);
      field.setValue("123");
      field.setTemplate(template);
      template.getFields().add(field);

      templateDao.saveAsNew(template);
   }
}
```

part of test output with `logging.level.org.hibernate: TRACE`

```
2016-02-15 11:30:03.686 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into field (id, field_name_id, operation_template_id, field_value) values (default, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into field (id, field_name_id, operation_template_id, field_value) values (default, ?, ?, ?)
2016-02-15 11:30:03.687 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Registering statement [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@6dc9da2d[sql=[insert into field (id, field_name_id, operation_template_id, field_value) values (default, ?, ?, ?)], parameters=[[null], [null], [null]]]]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.687 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : Dehydrating entity: [com.example.Template$Field#<null>]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.687 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2016-02-15 11:30:03.687 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.687 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.687 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [123]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper         : Natively generated identity: 1
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Releasing result set [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet@1d408060]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing result set [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet@1d408060]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Releasing statement [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@6dc9da2d[sql=[insert into field (id, field_name_id, operation_template_id, field_value) values (default, ?, ?, ?)], parameters=[[1], [1], [123]]]]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing prepared statement [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@6dc9da2d[sql=[insert into field (id, field_name_id, operation_template_id, field_value) values (default, ?, ?, ?)], parameters=[[1], [1], [123]]]]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[com.example.Template$Field#1]]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: com.example.Template.fields
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: com.example.Template
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing session
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for collection: com.example.Template.fields
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction   : Cascading to persist on flush: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Persistent instance of: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.688 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for collection: com.example.Template.fields
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2016-02-15 11:30:03.689 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
2016-02-15 11:30:03.691 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  : Collection found: [com.example.Template.fields#1], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
2016-02-15 11:30:03.691 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing unreferenced collections
2016-02-15 11:30:03.691 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
2016-02-15 11:30:03.692 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
2016-02-15 11:30:03.692 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
2016-02-15 11:30:03.692 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
2016-02-15 11:30:03.693 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.example.Template{clientId=null, name=test template name, id=1, fields=[com.example.Template$Field#1]}
2016-02-15 11:30:03.693 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.example.Template$Field{template=com.example.Template#1, name=com.example.Template$FieldType#1, id=1, value=123}
2016-02-15 11:30:03.693 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Executing flush
2016-02-15 11:30:03.693 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister      : Inserting collection: [com.example.Template.fields#1]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.693 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.batch.internal.BatchBuilderImpl  : Building batch [size=1]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.693 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update field set operation_template_id=? where id=?
    Hibernate: update field set operation_template_id=? where id=?
2016-02-15 11:30:03.693 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Registering statement [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@48df4071[sql=[update field set operation_template_id=? where id=?], parameters=[[null], [null]]]]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.693 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.694 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.695 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Releasing statement [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@48df4071[sql=[update field set operation_template_id=? where id=?], parameters=[[1], [1]]]]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.695 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing prepared statement [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@48df4071[sql=[update field set operation_template_id=? where id=?], parameters=[[1], [1]]]]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.695 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.695 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister      : Done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
2016-02-15 11:30:03.695 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.695 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Post flush
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl      : committing
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Automatically flushing session
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing session
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for collection: com.example.Template.fields
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction   : Cascading to persist on flush: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Persistent instance of: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.696 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for collection: com.example.Template.fields
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.example.Template$Field
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  : Collection found: [com.example.Template.fields#1], was: [com.example.Template.fields#1] (initialized)
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing unreferenced collections
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.example.Template{clientId=null, name=test template name, id=1, fields=[com.example.Template$Field#1]}
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.example.Template$Field{template=com.example.Template#1, name=com.example.Template$FieldType#1, id=1, value=123}
    2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Executing flush
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.697 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Post flush
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : before transaction completion
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction    : committed JDBC Connection
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction    : re-enabling autocommit
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionCoordinatorImpl     : after transaction completion
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : after transaction completion
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Closing session
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@5f14761c]
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Closing logical connection
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Releasing JDBC connection
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 DEBUG 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Released JDBC connection
2016-02-15 11:30:03.698 TRACE 8596 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Logical connection closed
```

And, finally, pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>demohbn</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <name>demo-hbn</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your `fields` is not `inverse`. This means that you have told Hibernate that `Template` is managing the value of the join column by setting the foreign key. If you want to prevent this behaviour, set the relationship to inverse, which tells Hibernate that `Field` will manage the foreign key - this means you need to set the `Template` on the `Field` before persisting rather than the `Field` on the `Template.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, Thanks for explanation!

Comment: np! Just make really sure you read up on what `inverse` means before implementing. It can have some unexpected effects, such as elements getting orphaned (or not!) when you didn't (or did!) expect them to. As with all optimisations; it comes at some cost to complexity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Many to one updating foreign key to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591684/hibernate-many-to-one-updating-foreign-key-to-null)

Comment: @dragan-bozanovic, It is very close, but not the same. I don't have "two independant associations, each incorrectly mapped to the same column". Btw, answered at first comment

Comment: @popalka You do. From Hibernate's perspective, those are two independent associations. Both sides are handling it, hence redundant update.