# OpenJPA - Null relationship values not being persisted on merge

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I'm having a problem understanding/figuring out a problem I'm having with OpenJPA and was hoping someone here can help out.

Basically, I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "images")
public class Image {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "fk_person-image")
    private Image image;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

As you can see, a `Person` can have an `Image`.  This is an optional column and supports a `null` value.  When a call from the REST Web Service comes in to update a `Person` changing the `Image` field, if the `Image` is being set to `null` the database isn't being updated, however if the `Image` is being changed to a different existing `Image`, it is saving.

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that the `Person` is coming in from the outside (detached), since if I obtain the `Person` from the DAO Service, set the `Image` to `null` and call the update/merge method using that instance it is updating the DB.

I was able to get it to work by adding the following property:

```
<property name="openjpa.DetachState" value="fetch-groups(DetachedStateField=false)"/>
```

However this seems to have some drawbacks as other relationships aren't being populated anymore when fetching from the DB.  (Rooms in a Building when retrieving the Building for example)

Has anyone encountered this before?  Any ideas on how this should be handled?  I'm tempted to test out Hibernate/Eclipselink to see if/how they handle this.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been racking my brain around this for the past 2 days.

Comment: how do you persist? can you post some snippets here as well?
I'm also wondering about the ManyToOne-Relationship which is not bidirectional, is that correct? Did you try using mappedBy? (it might not solve the actual problem, I'm just asking:))

Comment: did you try this approach?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591684/hibernate-many-to-one-updating-foreign-key-to-null
?